# How do I move JQuery draggable element without mouse

Tags: jquery, draggable, spam, emulation

Is there a different way of JQuery draggable element moving?
Think yourself as a spammer.

Comment: Ofcourse, it's being controlled clientside so you might as well move the draggable container yourself using javascript.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js to understand how draggable works. It might give you an idea.

Comment: Why is this tagged `spam`?  Care to elaborate on what this has with spammers to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should not be such a big deal, only calling the correct sequence of: `.mousedown()`, `.mousemove()` and `.mouseup()`

as the official documentation says (http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/):

> Bind an event handler to the "mousedown" JavaScript event, **or trigger that event on an element.**

the same is true for the other two jquery function descriptions

Comment: or did I miss the point here? after posting my answer I'm starting to feel like i did :)